# How many unlabelled non-isomorphic forests are there with 7 vertices and 4 components?

Tags: graph-theory

How many unlabelled non-isomorphic forests are there with 7 vertices and 4 components?

(A forest is a graph each of whose components is a tree.)

Comment: It would be better if you tell us where your difficulty is, by editing the question.

Comment: There are not very many such  forests; you could just draw pictures of all of them.

Comment: I get 7 of them

Comment: I only find 4. Are you sure your 7 are all non-isomorphic?